# Remove subcategories form Vanilla Forum sidebar

Tags: categories, sidebar, forum, vanilla-forums

I wish to display root categories in the Vanilla sidebar, however both categories and subcategories are displayed. The admin panel only gives the option of removing the sidebar all together or display root categories as headings.

I've narrowed down the PHP file responsible for this section of the sidebar it's located at: `applications/vanilla/views/modules/categories.php`

How would I modify this to prevent subcategories being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS, for example if you are using the Bootstrap theme, you can do this with:

```
 li.ClearFix.Depth2{
 display:none;
 }
```